# Elasticsearch uses wrong Case Folding for Unicode Characters

Tags: unicode, elasticsearch, icu

In one of my project, I am trying to use Elasticsearch (1.7) to query data. But, It returns different result for unicode characters depending on if they are uppercased or not. I try to use [icu_analyzer](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-analysis-icu) to get rid of problem.

Here is a small example to demonstrate my problem. My index is like this,

```
$ curl -X PUT http://localhost:9200/tr-test -d '
{
  "mappings": {
    "names": {
      "properties": {
        "name": {
          "type": "string"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "settings": {
    "index": {
      "number_of_shards": "5",
      "number_of_replicas": "1",
      "analysis": {
        "filter": {
          "nfkc_normalizer": {
            "type": "icu_normalizer",
            "name": "nfkc"
          }
        },
        "analyzer": {
          "my_lowercaser": {
            "tokenizer": "icu_tokenizer",
            "filter": [
              "nfkc_normalizer"
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}'
```

Here is a test data to demonstrate my problem.

```
$ curl -X POST http://10.22.20.140:9200/tr-test/_bulk -d '
{"index": {"_type":"names", "_index":"tr-test"}}
{"name":"BAHADIR"}'
```

Here is a similar query. If I query using `BAHADIR` as `query_string`, I can easily find my test data.

```
$ curl -X POST http://10.22.20.140:9200/tr-test/_search -d '
{
  "query": {
    "filtered": {
      "query": {
        "query_string": {
          "query": "BAHADIR"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}'
```

In Turkish, lowercased version of of `BAHADIR` is `bahadır`. I am expecting same result while querying with `bahadır`. But Elasticsearch cannot find my data. And I cannot fix that with using ICU for analysis. It works perfectly fine if I query with `bahadir`.

I already read [Living in a Unicode World](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/unicode-normalization.html) and [Unicode Case Folding](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/case-folding.html). But cannot fix my problem. I still cannot make elasticsearch to use correct case folding.

### Update

I also try to create my Index like this.

```
$ curl -X PUT http://localhost:9200/tr-test -d '
{
  "mappings": {
    "names": {
      "properties": {
        "name": {
          "type": "string",
          "analyzer" : "turkish"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "settings": {
    "index": {
      "number_of_shards": "5",
      "number_of_replicas": "1"
    }
  }
}'
```

But I am getting same results. My data can be found if I search using `BAHADIR` or `bahadir` but it cannot be found by searching `bahadır` which is correct lowercased version of `BAHADIR`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should try to use the [Turkish Language Analyzer](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-lang-analyzer.html#turkish-analyzer) in your setting.

```
{
  "mappings": {
    "names": {
      "properties": {
        "name": {
          "type":     "string",
          "analyzer": "turkish" 
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

As you can see in the implementation details, it also defines a `turkish_lowercase` so I guess it'll take care of your problems for you. If you don't want all the other features of the Turkish Analyzer, define a custom one with only `turkish_lowercase`

If you need a full text search on your `name` field, you should also change the query method to [match query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-match-query.html), which is the basic full text search method on a single field.

```
{
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "name": "bahadır"
    }
  }
}
```

On the other hand, [query string query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-query-string-query.html) is more complex and searches on multiple fields allowing an advanced syntax; It also has an option to pass the `analyzer` you want to use, so if you really needed this kind of query you should have tried passing `"analyzer": "turkish"` within the query. I'm not an expert of query string query though.

Comment: Thanks for quick response. But I am getting the same result. Now, I will try the settings in the link you provided.

Comment: @bhdrkn remember that your documents need to be re-indexed after having set the mapping

Comment: In order to be sure, I am deleting existing index and creating again with new mappings. And populate test data and query again. But nothing is changed.

Comment: @bhdrkn does it work with [match query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-match-query.html) ?

Comment: Many Thanks! It works! But I do not understand why? What is the difference between those two query? Do you have any suggested resources to understand elasticsearch better?